# Find the right response to a soap request (java-ws)

Tags: soap, soapheader, java-ws

I need to save the soap request and response in the database. Is there a simple way to find which response belongs to which request? Do we have something like sessionID in soap messages?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by setting a custom property in message request and get it from response.